# Reverse debugging with gnu gdb on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gdb, macports

I'm very interesting in ability to reverse debugging one immense xcode-based project on MacOS X. The problem is XCode 4.1 has gdb version 6.3.50, while reverse debugging presents starting from 7.0

So I installed gdb 7.3 via macports, but it rejects to recognize the executable at all with the message:

> GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3
>   Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html 
>   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
>   and "show warranty" for details. 
>   This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin11.1.0". 
>   For bug reporting instructions, please see: 
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/... 
>   "path/to/my.bundle.app/Content/MacOS/executable": not in executable format: File format not recognized

Does anyone know whether if is it possible to fix the problem ?

Comment: Question: what is "reverse debugging"?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/news/reversible.html
http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Reverse-Execution.html

Comment: I don't think this is causing your error, but the first link you provided lists the supported platforms, and OS X is not on that list.

Comment: Thanks... this is related to 7.0 I just hope it's somehow fixed for current 7.3. And anyway it's part 2, for now I can't even launch anything.
I have feeling it's some difference in binary formats but by some reason gdb is present in macports therefore it probably is able to launch something.